# How can I prevent a polynomial from being simplified?

Tags: polynomials, simplifying-expressions

I'm having a problem with polynomials. Let's say I have a polynomial "2x^2 - 5x + 6 - 3x^2" .. How can I check that this expression is not simplified ? Additionally, I would like to locate the uncombined terms (2x^2 and -3x^2) and print them. I tried a lot of polynomial built-in functions, all of them simplify the expression before output.. For example,

```
MonomialList[2 x^2 - 5 x + 6 - 3 x^2]
```

> ```
> {-x^2, -5 x, 6}
> ```

Is there any command to suppress automatic simplification ?
Thanks.

Comment: `List @@@ HoldForm[2 x^2 - 5 x + 6 - 3 x^2]` or `Cases[List @@@ HoldForm[2 x^2 - 5 x + 6 - 3 x^2], _ x^2, Infinity]`

Comment: Great, thanks Artes.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Artes in a comment to the question.

You can use

```
List @@@ HoldForm[2 x^2 - 5 x + 6 - 3 x^2]
```

or

```
Cases[List @@@ HoldForm[2 x^2 - 5 x + 6 - 3 x^2], _ x^2, Infinity]
```